# How to acces node server outside local network?

Tags: javascript, node.js

im writing a webserver in nodeJs as seen in the following code. I got the server working but sadly i cant acces the website outside my network (localhost). How can i do this?

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(80, function(){
console.log('Server running on 80...');
});
```

I also used this method to check if the other method was the problem.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res){
fs.readFile('Index.html', function (err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
})
}).listen(80);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding the port externally ?

```
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen({
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 80
}, function(){
console.log('Server running on 80...');
});
```

Comment: did you mean “the por**t**”? 

Comment: oops ! Well this is embarrasing :)

Comment: Hello Kevin, did you verify if the anti-virus or any other security tool isn't breaking the communication?